# Enter-PSSession cmdlet: Username containing a space is not working

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell 6.2, using the Enter-PSSession cmdlet, we have a username like "John Green".

Here the resulting error:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -Hostname 192.168.1.1 -Username "John Green" -SSHTransport
Enter-PSSession : The background process reported an error with the following message: The SSH client session has ended with error message: ssh: Could not resolve hostname john: No such host is known. .
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -Hostname 192.168.1.1 -Username "John Green" -SSHTra ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

Now a working example with "John.Green" (space replaced by a dot).

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -Hostname  192.168.1.1 -Username "John" -SSHTransport
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is <snip>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

A Linux like command would also gives an error in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> ssh "John Green"@192.168.1.1
At line:1 char:22
+ ssh "John Green"@192.168.1.1
+                      ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
At line:1 char:17
+ ssh "John Green"@192.168.1.1
+                 ~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@192' can be used only as an
argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$192'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName
```

Questions:

1. How a username with a space can be use with that kind of cmdlets?
2. If not possible, in PowerShell, how to start a SSH Session with an username containing a space?

Comment: Your error refers to host name. When using Enter-Pssession, use `ComputerName` instead of `HostName`. You can use PSCredentials along with using sessions

Comment: The error is caused by the space in the username.

Comment: no powershell 6 available, based on guess. try `-HostName "UserA B"@LinuxServer01` or `-HostName "UserA B@LinuxServer01"` or `-HostName UserA\ B@LinuxServer01` things like it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LarrySong the answers for SSH:

```
ssh "John Green@192.168.1.1"
```

The other proposed formats are not working.

The following command is working in PowerShell (no client side error) but because it replaces the space by "%20" the username isn't valid on the server side.

```
Enter-PSSession -Hostname "John Green@192.168.1.1" -SSHTransport
John%20Green@192.168.1.1's password:
Enter-PSSession : The background process reported an error with the following message: The SSH client session has ended with error message: Permission denied, please try again..
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`Enter-PSSession -HostName COMPUTERNAME -UserName 'John" "Green'`